# Include Cell ref in Google sheets to form a URL when using Importxml function

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can anyone help with an Error i'm getting when trying to include a Cell ref to form the URL on Google Sheets ImportXML?  I've followed other examples on here but I'm still getting an error returned.

```
=JOIN(",",Importxml(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",B1,"/cash-flow?p=",B1,""//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]//span"),1)")))
```

In addition, on other successful ImportXML commands I have running, the data is being returned as 20B (as an example) when I need this in my spreadsheet as 2,000,000,000.  Can this conversion be included as part of the Import command?

Comment: Looks like an issue with quotes. Can you give a sample of what your working formula looks like when you implement the value of B1 by hardcoding?

Comment: Here's an example:

=JOIN(",",Importxml(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/msft/cash-flow?p="msft"//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]//span"),1)")))

(ignore the https:// being stripped out above)

Comment: This formula does not work for me.

Comment: Well, i'm hoping somebody will be able to help me correct the formula so it does work.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HhrGUdvkVNTG2JouKybidXcBZXSBM9Xjl6Cyo5Ypn6E/edit?usp=sharing

B6 contains the ImportXML with the error i'm looking to fix.   B13 shows a trimmed down version that is returning ok results.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `=JOIN(",",Importxml(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",B1,"/cash-flow?p=",B1,"//*[@id='Col1-1-Financials-Proxy']//span"),1))` works for me, but I am not sure if those are the results you want. Given that `=Importxml(CONCATENATE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",B1,"/cash-flow?p=",B1,"//*[@id='Col1-1-Financials-Proxy']//span"),1)` returns 1 - what do you want to do with `join`? What data do you expect to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

replace A80 with your formulas:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A80, "\d+")*1000000000
```

[image: 0]